# Restructure data from array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hope it is not a stupid question. My array looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    pollType: "1",
    pollName: "Can you help me?",
    options: [
      { Options: "Yes, I can", PID: "oFnxh-NDdcP" },
      { Options: "No way!", PID: "d9A10-omlUd" }
    ]
  }
];
```

But I need to have it:

```
const result = [
  {
    pollType: "1",
    pollName: "Can you help me?",
    option1: "Yes, I can",
    pid1: "oFnxh-NDdcP",
    option2: "No way!",
    pid2: "d9A10-omlUd"
  }
];
```

Please don't get angry if it is so simple to do. I highly appreciate your help and if you do a an example so myself and other people can find it very useful in a future...

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var orig = [{"pollType":"1","pollName":"Can you help me?","options":[{"Options":"Yes, I can","PID":"oFnxh-NDdcP"},{"Options":"No way!","PID":"d9A10-omlUd"}]}]

    var newArr = [];
    orig.forEach(v => {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj.pollType = v.pollType;
        newObj.pollName = v.pollName;
        v.options.forEach((k, i) => {
            newObj["options" + (i + 1)] = k.Options;
            newObj["pid" + (i + 1)] = k.PID;
        });
        newArr.push(newObj);
    });

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aplet123